# Empty NSMutableArray , not sure why

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

Ok so I populate the array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *participants;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeofpm; i++){
        NSDictionary *pmpart_dict = [pm_participants objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *pmpart_email = [pmpart_dict objectForKey:@"email"];
        NSString *pmpart_email_extra = [@"pm" stringByAppendingString:pmpart_email];
        [participants setValue:pmpart_email forKey:pmpart_email_extra];
        NSLog(@"%@", participants);
    }
```

sizeofpm is 1. that is using count. to get the number of values in the array. How can i store values to that array? It doesnt seem to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to alloc it first. Try to change the first line to:

`NSMutableArray* participants = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

also using `setValue:forKey:` wont work with an `NSMutableArray` as an array has no key.

Try using `[participants addObject:pmpart_email];`.

Comment: I missed that, you missed the setValue:! Between us, we've got it covered.

Answer (score 2):

You don't create the array, you just declare it.

```
NSMutableArray *participants = [NSMutableArray array];
```

After that, `setValue:forKey:` will not add objects to an array. You need `addObject:`:

```
[participants addObject:pmpart_email];
```

There is no key.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value to an `NSMutableArray *participants` like how you assign values to an `NSDictionary` object. To assign values to `NSMutableArray` you can call `- (void)addObject:(id)anObject`

Answer (score 0):

So, I as some of the other answer have stated, you're missing your initializer for `participants`. However, judging by your use of `setValue:forKey:`, and how you appear to be structuring your data, you're not looking for `NSMutableArray`, but instead `NSMutableDictionary`. Arrays are simply lists, whereas dictionaries maintain key-value relationships, which you appear to be attempting to leverage.

Try this:

```
// some classes provide shorthand for `alloc/init`, such as `dictionary`
NSMutableDictionary *participants = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeofpm; i++){
    NSDictionary *pmpart_dict = [pm_participants objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *pmpart_email = [pmpart_dict objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSString *pmpart_email_extra = [@"pm" stringByAppendingString:pmpart_email];
    [participants setValue:pmpart_email forKey:pmpart_email_extra];
    NSLog(@"%@", participants);
}
```

This will give you a dictionary in the form of

```
{
    pmpart_email_extra: pmpart_email
}
```