# NSMutableArray always empty?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Still have some difficulties to understand Obj-C's gestion of memory and some of its concepts.

So my main class contains a `NSMutableArray` containing some characters and their list of weapons. It's like this :

**In Main class.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *players;
```

**In Main class.m's init**

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++)
{
    [players addObject:[[PlayerInGame alloc] init:[self.tabPlayers objectAtIndex:i] :[self.tabWeapons:objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

**PlayerInGame.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *weaponsList;
```

**PlayerInGame.m**

```
- (id) init : (Player*) player : (Weapon*) weapon
{
    [self.weaponsList addObject:weapon];
    // Then I try NSLog of weaponsList's count.
}
```

Here weaponsList is always empty. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty NSMutableArray , not sure why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632308/empty-nsmutablearray-not-sure-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are right. On any other language if you reference a unallocated object you will get a NullPointerException. But in objective C the method sent to nil just returns 0 and it won't crash the app.. If you want further read, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c)

That is why

```
[self.weaponsList addObject:weapon];
```

didn't crash, while in java if you try to add object to a unallocated array your program will crash.. As other answers pointed out, the statement

```
self.weaponsList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

alloc memory to store array, and a reference is given back to to variable weaponList.  Now weaponList != nil.

Comment: While the solution given is correct, the explanation is wrong.  You don't get an exception because nil is considered to be a valid object by the runtime and any message sent to nil returns straight away with a return value of 0 (or equivalently nil).  `[nil count]` therefore returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

You have to alloc your array before add any object in it. you can use following code in `viewDidLoad` method

```
 NSMutableArray *players = [[NSMutableArray allo]init]; 
 NSMutableArray weaponsList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen weaponList object allocation. Do you initialize it?

```
self.weaponsList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

PS: Minor advice. Method "- (id) init : (Player*) player : (Weapon*) weapon" signature will look better and being used easier if you change it as

```
- (id) initWithPlayer:(Player *)player weapon:(Weapon *)weapon
```

Answer (score 2):

I aslo suggest to change a bit your init syntax and init the array with object:

```
- (id) initWithPlayer:(Player *)aPlayer weapon:(Weapon *)aWeapon {
    self.weaponsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:aWeapon];
    [self.weaponsList retain];
    // remember to release inside dealloc, or use autorelease
}
```