# Why is count returning 0 for number of objects in my array when there should be 3?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, count

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

```
    NSMutableArray *myMute;
    NSString *stringOne = @"This is string 1";
    NSString *stringTwo = @"This is string 2";
    NSString *stringThree = @"This is string 3";

    [myMute addObject: stringOne];
    [myMute addObject: stringTwo];
    [myMute addObject: stringThree];

    NSLog(@"There are %li objects in the myMute array", [myMute count]);


    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: and [Empty NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632308/), [NSMutableArray always emtpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892597/), [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851926/), [Cannot add items to NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125326/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just allocate array   you create  nil array you have to allocate it memory with new or alloc

```
NSMutableArray *myMute = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSString *stringOne = @"This is string 1";
    NSString *stringTwo = @"This is string 2";
    NSString *stringThree = @"This is string 3";

    [myMute addObject: stringOne];
    [myMute addObject: stringTwo];
    [myMute addObject: stringThree];

    NSLog(@"There are %li objects in the myMute array", [myMute count]);


    return 0;
```